# What unit is the `dist` argument in `st_buffer` set to by default?

Tags: r, r-sf

I have the following map of Mexico. It shows all of its municipalities and around 400 weather stations.

[image: Mexico]

I want to create a 10km buffer around each station and eventually, associate each municipality to a station that is located within each radius.

The map and the stations are stored on separate sf objects. I tired the following:

```
buffers <- st_buffer(stations, dist = 1)
```

I thought the `dist` argument was set to kilometers, so I tried `dist = 10`. Unfortunately, this returned **HUGE** buffers for each station. That's why I am using `dist = 1`, but even these buffers are as big as a state! [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704878/circle-around-a-geographic-point-with-st-buffer), suggests I transform my stations to *Irish Grid*, but I couldn't replicate the accepted answer. I am now wondering what unit the `dist` argument is set to.

From the aforementioned question, I assume it's set to degrees. How can I set a 10km buffer around each station?

Additional info:

My CRS is set to 4326 on both objects (the Mexican map and the stations).

This is my `stations` data:

```
> dput(head(stations))
structure(list(station_number = c(1004L, 1005L, 1008L, 1012L, 
1017L, 1018L), station_alt = c(1925, 1844, 2323, 1589, 2172, 
2053), month = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), Mean_min = c(11.6, 
12.75, 12.25, 13.9666666666667, 12.9, 12.6833333333333), Mean_max = c(26.9333333333333, 
26.85, 24.0833333333333, 29.0333333333333, 24.8666666666667, 
26.1333333333333), months_observed = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(-102.199, 22.001), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-102.372, 21.781), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-102.135, 22.203), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-102.802, 21.794), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-102.444, 22.233), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-102.415, 22.141), class = c("XY", 
"POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -102.802, 
ymin = 21.781, xmax = -102.135, ymax = 22.233), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    epsg = NA_integer_, proj4string = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(station_number = NA_integer_, 
station_alt = NA_integer_, month = NA_integer_, Mean_min = NA_integer_, 
Mean_max = NA_integer_, months_observed = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The documentation seems to say that the value of `st_crs(stations)$units` would be used. Is that not the case? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I updated the post (added `stations` using `dput`). As for your question, I have no idea if the unit is set to the same unit as `stations`. How can I verify that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your coordinates are long/lat, so the distance will be in degrees. You should first project to a spatial reference in meter units and then take 10 000 meters.

The manual of `st_buffer` says this about the dist argument:

> in case dist is a units object, it should be convertible to
>   arc_degree if x has geographic coordinates, and to st_crs(x)$units
>   otherwise

If you leave the coordinates in 4326 you should be able to take something like 0.1 which should be about 11 km for Mexico, but you will see a warning message:

> In st_buffer.sfc(st_geometry(x), dist, nQuadSegs, endCapStyle =
>   endCapStyle,  :   st_buffer does not correctly buffer
>   longitude/latitude data

So first convert to another projection (in meter) and enter the distance in meters. This should work, which uses [EPSG 7801](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7801/):

```
library(sf)

pois <- st_as_sf(stations)
st_crs(pois) <- 4326
pois <- st_transform(pois, crs = 7801)
plot(st_geometry(pois))

buff <- st_buffer(pois, dist = 10000)
plot(st_geometry(buff), add = TRUE)
```

Control with leaflet and the measure tool:

```
buff <- st_transform(buff, crs = 4326)

library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMeasure(primaryLengthUnit = "meters") %>% 
  addMarkers(data = pois) %>% 
  addPolygons(data = buff)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did exactly what you did and then changed `buff` back to EPSG 4326 so i could keep working with the Mexican map, the stations and the buffers as before. Do you see any inconvencience in doing this?

Comment: No thats totally correct. :) Although I'm not sure right if 6829 is correct. 7801 Looks more correct to me.

Comment: Do you mean the 6829 in `pois <- st_transform(pois, crs = 6829)`?

Comment: Yes, I changed it to 7801. I'll add some leaflet code so you can measure the buffer.

Comment: how do you know 7801 or 6829 are appropriate and in meters?